# Windows 11 opens WebDav in Browser instead of File Explorer by accessing via address bar

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, webdav, windows-11-v23h2

Currently I am facing a problem with the new version of Windows 11. By trying to access an WebDAV link via address bar (File Explorer) I get forwarded in my browser.

In previous Version of Windows 11 and 10 I was able to open temporary an WebDAV session without mapping an network drive by using the address bar.

Unfortunately I could not find any information about how to edit this kind of settings.

I would be very grateful for a suggested solution!